# How to load php script into div with jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#S1").change(function()
    {
        var IDCat=this.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'product_modify.php',
            data: {IDCat:IDCat},
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#p1").text(data);
                $("#tempForm").load('tv_form.php');
            }                    
        });
    });
});
```

It is my code , in `load()` function when I call  'tv_form.html' file it works, but when i call 'tv_form.php' it doesn't work , error is 403 forbidden 
where is the problem ? .html works, but `.php` doesn't work.

Comment: make sure your file name and you should run your php file from server.

Comment: PHP files are not meant to be ran from the client side. It's the reason why it's called a server script. You can have the PHP file give you a set of HTML elements to be inserted.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved it was about .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Add URL instead of file name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#S1").change(function()
  {
    var IDCat=this.value;
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'product_modify.php',
            data: {IDCat:IDCat},
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#p1").text(data);
                $("#tempForm").load('URL to tv_form.php'); // www.example.com/file.php
            }
        });
      });
});
```