# How to load blade or php content into a view via ajax/jquery in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

As the title says, I am trying to dynamically load content in a view using ajax requests. I know this can be done if you are using `html` elements e.g. `("#div_place").html(<p>...)`. The problem lies when I would like to load some php/blade objects into a div for instance. Is this possible or is there a different way to go about achieving the result I want.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty straightforward. Assuming you're using jQuery...

1. create a route that will respond to the AJAX call and return an HTML fragment

   ```
   Route::get('test', function(){

       // this returns the contents of the rendered template to the client as a string
       return View::make("mytemplate")
           ->with("value", "something")
           ->render();

   });
   ```
2. in your javascript:

   ```
   $.get(
       "test",
       function (data) {
           $("#my-content-div").html(data);
       }
   );
   ```

Comment: Thanks, just did some more digging and realized something similar to this was what I had to do.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this is not the way to go. Let's say you have a `<header>` some *content* inside a `<div id="xhr">` and a `<footer>`. You don't want to load the `<header>` and `<footer>` over and over again, right? So in this case you might want to have a different approach.

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman you may be right. In this question the OP was asking how to dynamically load blade templates - a blade template compiles to HTML (usually), so this seemed like the most direct answer to the question. Personally, I'd just pass data back & forth, not HTML, but that relies on Javascript to render it, which (IMHO) was outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: by the way I think you want to do a `$.get(..)` ajax request in your javascript.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! I can't believe no one noticed that error in three years :-D

Answer (score -2):

After some digging some more I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183313/how-to-load-php-script-into-div-with-jquery-ajax)  which helped me to solve the problem.

You have to use the `.load("url/page/...")` via jquery and then set a route in the routes.php file that displays a view with the data that needs to be loaded e.g.

```
Route::get('/url/page/...', function(){
    return View::make('test');
});
```

This returns the necessary php code which needed to be loaded dynamically, cheers.